# serializer.data breaks order of list in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

### Serializer class

```
class VariantListCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Variant
```

### Model Class

```
class Variant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256,
    default='',
    verbose_name=_('name'),
    help_text=_('Name of variant'))
```

### created some objects of the model class

```
obj1 = Variant()
obj1.save()
obj2 = Variant()
obj2.save()
obj3 = Variant()
obj3.save()
```

### Serializing object list of model class 'Variant'

```
object_list = [obj3, obj1, obj2]
serializer = VariantListCreateSerializer(object_list, many=True,
                                    **extra)
```

after serializing the list **serializer.data** gives the list as the following order:

```
obj1
obj2
obj3
```

but i want the objects same as the order i passed to the serializer class.

```
obj3
obj1
obj2
```

how?